# RStudio will not write a .bbl file when compiling .Rnw file with citations in natbib

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, sweave

I have a .Rnw file (Test.Rnw) in RStudio with citations. The .bib file is in the same folder as the .Rnw file, but when I compile the .Rnw file, no .bbl file is written out and I get the error:

```
There were undefined citations
```

And checking the log, I find, as expected:

```
No file Test.bbl
```

This is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[sort,comma,numbers,super]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\title{Analysis}
\author{Amanda E. Gentry}
\date{April 7, 2019}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some text\citep{Hoerl70}. More text\citep{Tibshirani96}. Even more text\citep{Zou05}.

Code section below:
<<loading, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=F, warning=F>>=
x <- seq(1:10)
summary(x)
@

\bibliography{Refs}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

I have searched the web for answers but found nothing that directly relates to this issue or how to fix it so far.

Interestingly enough, this same code will compile properly in RStudio version 1.1.143 (which I have installed on another machine) but will not compile in the newest version of RStudio nor on any of the older versions (going back about 3 versions) and 1.1.143 is not an archived version currently available for download.

I have posted this issue to the RStudio Community board without luck so far.

Edits:
Here is the .bib file I'm using

```
@Article{Hoerl70,
  author={Arthur E. Hoerl and Robert W. Kennard},
  title={Ridge Regression: Biased Estimation for Nonorthogonal Problems},
  journal={Technometrics},
  volume={12},
  number={1},
  year={1970},
  pages={55-67}
}

@article{Tibshirani96,
    author={Robert Tibshirani},
    title={Regression Shrinkage and Selection via the Lasso},
    journal={Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series B},
    volume={58},
    number={1},
    year={1996},
    pages={267-288}
    }

@Article{Zou05,
  author={Hui Zou and Trevor Hastie},
  title={Regularization and variable selection via the elastic net},
  journal={Journal of the Royal Statistical Society Series B-Statistical Methodology},
  volume={67},
  number={Part 2},
  pages={301-320},
  year={2005}
}
```

And this is a screen grab of the error messages:

[image: Error messages]

Comment: If you click on "Issues" in the console pane, do you see any other issues?  When I run it the bbl file is created (but I get warnings about missing references, because I didn't create a real `Refs.bib` file).

Comment: @user2554330 I added a snapshot of the error messages (I only get the one I mentioned and the 3 "undefined citations" for each of the three references) and also the .bib file I'm using. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The code seems to work fine. Is there a `.blg` file in your folder? If yes, please show the content.

Comment: @samcarter There does not seem to be a .blg file in the folder.

Comment: @A.E.Gentry OK, then the problem is probably that bibtex was not run. Can you somewhere select which commands are used by rstudio to compile your file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the error with Rstudio pre-realease version 1.2.1330 on Linux using either `Sweave`  or `knitr` for pre-processing. In the latter case without `\SweaveOpts`.

Comment: @samcarter not that I can find. The options in RStudio seem very limited. It's not my favorite program, but (until I hit this issue) it was the only one I could find that allows both LaTex compiling and editing a .Rnw file with R console access.

Comment: @A.E.Gentry Are you comfortable using the command line?

Comment: @RalfStubner I am running RStudio 1.2.1335 on MacOS High Sierra v10.13.6, so perhaps the problem is OS-specific?

Comment: @samcarter moderately so, yes

Comment: @A.E.Gentry If you can navigate to the folder `~/Documents/UKB/` and run `bibtex Test` and then compile again with Rstudio it might work. Can you test this?

Comment: @samcarter I followed your instructions and running twice in RStudio produced the file with proper citations. This certainly is a solution! Although, I wish I knew how to change the RStudio options so it would function properly with a single click.

Comment: Looks to be OS specific. I would suggest reposting it in tehe RStudio community, but this time in IDE category: https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide. Please mention your OS and RStudio version right away.

Comment: @RalfStubner I've just done that, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Please feel free to chime in or upvote on this Github issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2788 Once it is implemented, I believe your problem will be gone.

Comment: I asked again in the rstudio community and am waiting for a response (https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-sweave-does-not-create-a-bbl-file-on-linux-ubuntu/35110), but meanwhile you can follow the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960392/impossible-to-cite-with-biblatex-in-r-sweave/56985098?noredirect=1#comment100505321_56985098