# R Sweave does not compile .bbl file

Tags: r, sweave

R Sweave does not compile automatically the .bbl file necessary to detect citations in the text. I found a solution with compiling in another program (https://community.rstudio.com/t/impossible-to-cite-with-biblatex-in-r-sweave/35008/2) but it would much more convenient not to compile three times the same file (on two different softwares).

One of the comments here ([RStudio will not write a .bbl file when compiling .Rnw file with citations in natbib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682811/rstudio-will-not-write-a-bbl-file-when-compiling-rnw-file-with-citations-in-na)) mentioned the fact that maybe R Sweave does not run bibtex. Is there something to do to fix this problem ?

(Question also asked here : https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-sweave-does-not-create-a-bbl-file-on-linux-ubuntu/35110)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the new release (just upgraded) with .Rnw files that compiled fine (with citations) before.

Comment: I reinstalled MikTex on Windows and still don't have any luck compiling. If I open the created .tex file, it compiles perfectly in TeXStudio. This is only a temporary solution though.

Comment: Yes, this works but it would be better to be able to compile directly from R sweave

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I searched a lot but it seems that this is a problem linked to R Studio in general. That's why I posted the same question on the R Studio community forum, but I have had no answers so far

Comment: I just reverted back to the old version of RStudio and it still doesn't work like it did before I updated.

Comment: I tried R Sweave for the first time a couple of months ago, never used it with an older version of R Studio

Comment: I tried some new things and posted about it on [sweave.](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-sweave-bibtex-citations/37832) I've found a few work arounds as you did, but nothing that works as it should.

Comment: I uninstalled MikTeX and installed TinyTeX and now it works -- no idea why. Looks like all my other .tex files are running okay for now too. Really weird, but I feel lucky to have randomly gotten it to work. [Details](https://rdrr.io/cran/tinytex/man/install_tinytex.html)

Comment: It does not work for me but I uninstalled only miktex and not the tex distribution on my computer (running on Ubuntu). I don't want to uninstall the complete tex distribution because I won't write every tex document on Rstudio so waiting for a less restrictive solution, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I just reinstalled MiKTeX and everything works side by side -- I think just setting up Rstudio to use TinyTeX is the solution. Happy for someone that knows more than me to correct me on that, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution, here's what I did :

- based on the comments of [user1329307](/questions/tagged/user1329307), I uninstalled MikTeX and the complete TeX distributions on my computer. Since I use Ubuntu, I used `purge` to remove MikTeX, TeXLive, tex-commons, etc.
- then, I installed (or re-installed) TinyTeX (details [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/tinytex/man/install_tinytex.html))
- I installed manually the packages I needed with `tlmgr_install()`. Normally, it can be done automatically but that's what I did.
- finally, I replaced `biber` by `bibtex` in `\usepackage[backend = biber]{biblatex}` ([this person](https://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/) explains why it is important)

This last step made it work, but I don't know if the previous ones are important or not. Since [user1329307](/questions/tagged/user1329307) succeeded in compiling the bibliography too, I suppose it is necessary but there's no way for me to prove it.

Anyway, now, when I compile the Sweave document, the bibliography is directly created. Thanks a lot to [user1329307](/questions/tagged/user1329307) for his/her ideas.

Edit : I re-installed MikTeX after all of this and it works too.